# Tracking down unhandled asp.net exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have an asp.net web application and for one of our users, an exception is thrown on a specific page when they click on a button. I have not been able to recreate this issue, but the system is logging an exception when the client gets the exception. The problem is, I don't know where the exception is being generated. When we log an exception, we call the ToString() method on the exception to get the stack trace. It's a parsing error, but I can't tell where it's coming from. Here's the exception as we logged it:

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options,
>   NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
>   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style,
>   NumberFormatInfo info)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.Int32Converter.FromString(String value,
>   NumberFormatInfo formatInfo)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext
>   context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)

I assume this is being logged by the following code in the Global.asax

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
        if (Server.GetLastError() != null)
        {
            Exception objErr = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
            objErr.WriteExceptionLog();
        }
    }
```

However, I don't know where this code is getting called from or how to find out. Any ideas on where I can look or if I need to do something different when I'm logging the exception?

Comment: You could try logging the inner exceptions as well.  You also no that it is somewhere you are converting a string to a number.  I don't know how often you are doing that, but you could always search you project for where you are making the converstion and switch to using something like a tryparse instead.

Comment: What happens if you log `Server.GetLastError()` instead? And make sure you're logging `Server.GetLastError().ToString()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
    if (Server.GetLastError() != null)
    {
        Exception err = Server.GetLastError().InnerException;

        // handle error here

        Server.ClearError();
    }
}
```

Comment: what if there isn't an inner exception?

Comment: There should be, as ``Server.GetLastError()`` will always get you an ``HttpUnhandledException`` in this scenario, which is essentially a wrapper.

Comment: ah... as you can tell, I don't do `GetLastError()` often :-)

Comment: I'll give this a try. I should know something on Friday. Thanks.

Comment: I ended up just using Server.GetLastError() without any additional properties specified. We log the entire stack trace, so the top level exception was what we needed. Also, I was able to track down the issue. Thanks.